how to convert po translation file with msgid as original translation string and msgstr as translated string to 2 different json files (en and fr)
I have a .po file which follows the following format (keeping it slim - notice there is only a msgid and mstr as part of each set of strings):
msgid "hello everyone"
msgstr "bonjour toute la monde"

The msgid is the original text in english, and the msgstr is the translated text in french.
We are currently trying to use the library i18next-gettext-converter, but not sure how to do such a task with the library (if even possible), or if there's a different javascript library that could meet our needs.
We would want our one large .po file to be able to generate 1 english translation and 1 french translation file so the react-i18next library can be used.
I've tried using the cli options with the -l and -s flags, and played around with the -K option flags, but nothing seems to even come close.

I think you should read the .po file and write a new file as you want, without any library, here is a snippet for you to start:
// node format.js
const fs = require('fs');

function parsePoFile(poFilePath) {
    const content = fs.readFileSync(poFilePath, 'utf8');
    const entries = content.split('\n\n').map(entry => {
        const lines = entry.trim().split('\n');
        const msgid = lines.find(line => line.startsWith('msgid')).split('msgid ')[1];
        const msgstr = lines.find(line => line.startsWith('msgstr')).split('msgstr ')[1];
        return { msgid, msgstr };
    });
    return entries;
}

function generateTranslationFile(entries, lang) {
    const translations = entries.reduce((acc, entry) => {
        acc[entry.msgid] = entry.msgstr;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    fs.writeFileSync(`translations.${lang}.json`, JSON.stringify(translations, null, 2), 'utf8');
}

const poFilePath = 'your_po_file.po';
const entries = parsePoFile(poFilePath);
generateTranslationFile(entries, 'en'); // English translation file
generateTranslationFile(entries, 'fr'); // French translation file



Thanks for this. I think the issue may be that there is a lot of 'in between' steps such as pluralization, etc that the converter takes care of.

hmm I see... Will be hard to do it procedurally, can you share some examples from .po file?

I'm not sure you fully described the problem, because i18next-gettext-converter seems to do exactly what you need.
You can use it in command line by installing it globally:
npm install i18next-conv -g

So assuming you have test.po file with content:
msgid "hello everyone"
msgstr "bonjour toute la monde"

You can execute command:
i18next-conv -l fr -s test.po -t test.fr.json

And it will create test.fr.json for you:
{
    "hello everyone": "bonjour toute la monde"
}

Is that what you want to achieve?
Otherwise, please, provide a sample of source and desired result files.
